# How to properly configure docker-compose keycloak in combination with the BFF template?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, spring-security, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I am developing a website(SPA) using `Vue.js` and `Spring Boot` based on the `BFF` tutorial provided from [spring-addons](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff).

At some point I needed to optimize the development process, I came to the conclusion that the reverse proxy server (bff gateway) would not change often during development and it was time to stop running it manually from the IDEA. Therefore, need to package it into a `docker image` and run it through `docker-compose` along with other services (keycloak and postgresql). Trying to do this, I ran into certain problems that I do not know how to solve.

When launching `bff-gateway` from `docker` and trying to log in to `keycloak`, as expected according to the tutorial, a request is made to `http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/keycloak`

The response to the request is 304 redirect to location: `http://keycloak:9090/realms/...` which leads to "Unable to access the site"

How should I configure this correctly so that it works as it should?

`docker-compose.yaml`:

```yaml
services:
  gateway:
    image: 'bff-gateway:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    container_name: 'bff'
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: 'prod-docker'
    networks:
      - 'keycloak-network'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    depends_on:
      keycloak:
        condition: 'service_healthy'
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:latest'
    container_name: 'postgres-db'
    restart: 'always'
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: 'keycloakdb'
      POSTGRES_USER: 'keycloakuser'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'keycloakpass'
    networks:
      - 'keycloak-network'
    healthcheck:
      test: pg_isready -U keycloakuser -d keycloakdb
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 5s
  keycloak:
    container_name: 'keycloak'
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.4
    restart: 'always'
    volumes:
      - keycloak_data:/opt/keycloak/data/
    environment:
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: true
      DB_VENDOR: 'POSTGRES'
      DB_ADDR: 'postgres'
      DB_DATABASE: 'keycloakdb'
      DB_SCHEMA: 'public'
      KEYCLOAK_USER: 'user'
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: 'user'
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: 'admin'
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: 'admin'
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    command:
      - "start-dev"
      - "--http-port=9090"
    networks:
      - 'keycloak-network'
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: 'service_healthy'
    healthcheck:
      # I have not found another way to do this, if you know, then please help: https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/18923/43435
      test: [ 'CMD-SHELL', '[ -f /tmp/HealthCheck.java ] || echo "public class HealthCheck { public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Throwable { System.exit(java.net.HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK == ((java.net.HttpURLConnection) java.net.URI.create(args[0]).toURL().openConnection()).getResponseCode() ? 0 : 1); } }" > /tmp/HealthCheck.java && java /tmp/HealthCheck.java http://localhost:9090/health/live' ]
      start_period: 10s
      interval: 15s
      retries: 3
      timeout: 5s

networks:
  keycloak-network:
    driver: 'bridge'

volumes:
  postgres_data:
    driver: 'local'
  keycloak_data:
    driver: 'local'
```

bff-gateway `prod-docker` profile:

```yaml
issuer: http://keycloak:9090/realms/realm-id
# At the time of development, the common frontend and backend application is launched from IDEA
backend-api-uri: ${scheme}://host.docker.internal:8090/api
ui-uri: ${scheme}://host.docker.internal:1000
```

Base configuration of bff-gateway corresponds to the [tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/samples/tutorials/bff/backend/with-c4-soft/bff-c4/src/main/resources/application.yml).